# ReCaptchaV2 Callback function + Submit button

Tags: python, recaptcha

Need some help about captcha solving with API. I use Python.
This is site where captcha is - https://www.inipec.gov.it/cerca-pec/-/pecs/companies
I use API (https://azcaptcha.com/document) to solve Captcha. When captcha has solved, the result needs to be paste in special form.
But there is no submit button to pass it.
[image]

THere is some advice in API documentation:

> Sometimes there's no submit button and a callback function is used
>   isntead. The function is executed when reCaptcha is solved.
>
> Callback function is usually defined in data-callback parameter of
>   reCaptcha, for example:
>
> data-callback="myCallbackFunction"

My question is: what is callback function, and how can i do it in Python.
Thanks.